# Array sorting date is not working as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, sorting

I have an array which contains these values

```
daterangefordb = [ "12/16/2015", "11/25/2015", "01/06/2016", "12/30/2015" ]
```

When I sort I get this using `daterangefordb.sort()`:

```
[ "01/06/2016", "11/25/2015", "12/16/2015", "12/30/2015" ]
```

Whereas, expected sort values should be -

```
[ "11/25/2015", "12/16/2015", "12/30/2015", "01/06/2016" ]
```

Any solutions?

Comment: This is because you are trying to sort string and not date objects

Comment: and how to sort it by date?

Comment: Convert it to date object first. Refer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5619202/converting-string-to-date-in-js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `sort()` method with no function provided to it will perform a simple alphanumeric sort on the values of the array as strings. In your case you need to convert them to dates before comparing. Try this:

```
var sorted = daterangefordb.sort(function(a, b) {
    var aDate = new Date(a);
    var bDate = new Date(b);
    if (aDate < bDate)
        return -1;
    else if (aDate > bDate)
        return 1;
    return 0;
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/n01un9hz/)

Answer (score 0):

These are strings, therefore properly sorted . If you wish to sort them as daes, then convert them to dates

```
new Date( "11-05-2015".replace( /(\d{2})-(\d{2})-(\d{4})/, "$2/$1/$3") );
```

Something like this works